# Google drive authentication error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railsapps

Running OSX Mavericks, ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin13.0], rvm 1.25.23 (master), and rails-4.1.0 (allegedly)

I'm working through the [railsapps.org](http://railsapps.github.io/) book on [learning rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html) and am stuck at "Spreadsheet Connection".  I have the code exactly as the book spells out, and I have set up an application specific password for Google Drive and tested it.  My code looks like the following:

```
def update_spreadsheet
connection = GoogleDrive.login(Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username, Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password)
ss = connection.spreadsheet_by_title('Learn-Rails-Example')
if ss.nil?
  ss = connection.create_spreadsheet('Learn-Rails-Example')
end
```

My secrets.yml file contains the following:

```
development:
email_provider_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>
email_provider_password: <%= ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"] %>

mailchimp_api_key: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"] %>
mailchimp_list_id: <%= ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"] %>
```

and I have my .bashrc file configured correctly per the tutorial.

When I enter the contact form info and press 'submit', I get the following error:

```
GoogleDrive::AuthenticationError at /contacts
Authentication failed for : Response code 403 for post https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin: Error=BadAuthentication
```

If I go up and hard code the login and app-specific password in place of `Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username` and `Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password` it works just fine.  As a newbie, I'm unable to follow the code to understand where or how `Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username` gets pointed to my .bashrc settings.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Jeff

Comment: Possible problem: Your password contains punctuation characters.

Comment: Your .bashrc settings create a Unix environment variable. The variable  `ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]` obtains the Unix environment variable from the Unix environment. It's just magic :-) which means you'd have to delve deep into very technical territory to learn how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If your Gmail password contains punctuation characters such as ! and @, surround the password with single quotes before setting the Unix environment variable, like this:

```
export GMAIL_PASSWORD="'my@#$%&!password'"
```

Comment: That's not the problem  The password (application specific) is all lower case letters.  I tried with and without single quotes.  It makes no difference.  I get the same error.  I can hand stuff the address and password into secrets.yml as well and it works.

Comment: It's likely you have a problem with setting Unix environment variables. It's an issue with your system configuration, not Rails or the learn-rails app. Try http://serverfault.com/ for help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue following the tutorial as well. Hardcoded the username and pw as you have done and it worked. I fixed it by putting the bunch of exports in my .bash_profile instead of .bashrc. Don't forget to restart your bash so that the updated environment is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same problem where hard coding works but env variables do not.  I tried putting the exports in .bash_profile and .bashrc too.

What worked for me was to add the exports to my .profile.

Running mavericks 10.9.4

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get around this error by removing some stray RVM commands in the .bashrc file.  My .bash_profile file is completely blank now and my .bashrc only 6 exports commands.